# Trying to convert open processing code into pj.5s

Tags: java, html, css, arraylist, p5.js

I have no clue how to change this into p5.js. Just trying to work on conversions. Please help me get this code to work in p5.js.

I know that this is old code and p5.js have different rules. Maybe the array isn't working. I have no clue.

```
    Myself myself;
ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;
`enter code here`ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;
ArrayList<Bullet> myBullets;
ArrayList<Bullet> eneBullets;

void setup(){

  size(640, 640);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  myself = new Myself();
  enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
  myBullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
  eneBullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>(); 
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  myself.display();
  for(Enemy enemy: enemies){
    enemy.display();
  }
  for(Bullet bullet: myBullets){
    bullet.display();
  }
  for(Bullet bullet: eneBullets){
    bullet.display();
  }

  myself.update();
  ArrayList<Enemy> nextEnemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
  for(Enemy enemy: enemies){
    enemy.update();
    if(!enemy.isDead){
      nextEnemies.add(enemy);
    }
  }
  enemies = nextEnemies;
  ArrayList<Bullet> nextMyBullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
  for(Bullet bullet: myBullets){
    bullet.update();
    if(!bullet.isDead){
      nextMyBullets.add(bullet);
    }
  }
  myBullets = nextMyBullets;
  ArrayList<Bullet> nextEneBullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
  for(Bullet bullet: eneBullets){
    bullet.update();
    if(!bullet.isDead){
      nextEneBullets.add(bullet);
    }
  }
  eneBullets = nextEneBullets;
  if(random(1) < 0.02){
    enemies.add(new Enemy());
  }
}

class Myself{

  PVector loc;
  float size;
  int coolingTime;
  boolean isDead;

  Myself(){
    size = 25;
    loc = new PVector(width / 2, height - size / 2 - 10);
    coolingTime = 0;
    isDead = false;
  }

  void display(){
    if(isDead){
      fill(255, 255, 0);
      stroke(0, 255, 0); 
    } else {
      noFill();
      stroke(0, 255, 0);
    }
    rect(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);
  }

  void update(){
    isDead = false;
    float dmx = mouseX - loc.x;
    dmx = constrain(dmx, -5, 5);
    loc.x += dmx;
    coolingTime++;
    if(mousePressed && coolingTime >= 10){
      myBullets.add(new Bullet());
      coolingTime = 0;
    }
    for(Bullet b: eneBullets){
      if((loc.x - size / 2 <= b.loc.x && b.loc.x <= loc.x + size / 2)
         && (loc.y - size / 2 <= b.loc.y && b.loc.y <= loc.y + size / 2)){
        isDead = true;
        b.isDead = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    for(Enemy e: enemies){
      if(abs(loc.x - e.loc.x) < size / 2 + e.size / 2 && abs(loc.y - e.loc.y) < size / 2 + e.size / 2){
        isDead = true;
        e.isDead = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

class Bullet{

  PVector loc;
  float vel;
  boolean isMine;
  boolean isDead;

  Bullet(){
    loc = new PVector(myself.loc.x, myself.loc.y);
    vel = -10;
    isMine = true;
  }

  Bullet(Enemy enemy){
    loc = new PVector(enemy.loc.x, enemy.loc.y);
    vel = 5;
    isMine = false;
  }

  void display(){
    if(isMine){
      stroke(0, 255, 0);
    } else {
      stroke(255, 0, 0);    
    }
    line(loc.x, loc.y, loc.x, loc.y + vel);    
  }

  void update(){
    loc.y += vel;
    if((vel > 0 && loc.y > height) || (vel < 0 && loc.y < 0)){
      isDead = true;
    }
  }  
}

class Enemy{

  PVector loc;
  float vel;
  float size;
  int coolingTime;
  boolean isDead;

  Enemy(){
    size = 25;
    loc = new PVector(random(size / 2, width - size / 2), -size / 2);
    vel = 3;
    coolingTime = int(random(60));
    isDead = false;
  }

  void display(){
    noFill();
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    rect(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);
  }

  void update(){
    loc.y += vel;
    if(loc.y > height){
      isDead = true;
    }
    coolingTime++;
    if(coolingTime >= 60){
      eneBullets.add(new Bullet(this));
      coolingTime = 0;
    }
    for(Bullet b: myBullets){
      if((loc.x - size / 2 <= b.loc.x && b.loc.x <= loc.x + size / 2)
         && (loc.y - size / 2 <= b.loc.y && b.loc.y <= loc.y + size / 2)){
        isDead = true;
        b.isDead = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

If you could just tell me what parts i need to change or fix it it would help me a lot thankyou.

Comment: What code is this (looks like Java) and what exactly you are trying to achieve in another language? What have you done so far and what was the failure/problem? If you are more specific then more people can help you.

Comment: It's a simple 2D shooter game. I just wanted to make the same game in p5.js

Comment: I was asking about the code language used, so now you've added java, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to translate code line-by-line. Instead, you need to take a step back and understand what the program does, and then you implement that in the target language.

They syntax for Processing (which is based on Java) is very different from the syntax for p5.js (which is based on JavaScript).

Instead of trying to "convert" the code, you need to think in terms of what the code actually does. And then start with a new program in p5.js and do that using p5.js. It's not always going to be a line-by-line conversion.

Answer (score 0):

here's your code:

```
 class myself{
constructor()
{
this.x = 0;
this.y = height-35;
this.size = 25;
this.health = 25;
this.cooldown = 0;
this.plrBullets = [];


}update(){this.cooldown++;

if (mouseIsPressed && this.cooldown>10)
{
  this.cooldown = 0;
  this.plrBullets.push(new Bullet(true,this.x,this.y));
}

let nextPlrBullets = [];
for (let i = 0; i<this.plrBullets.length; i++)
{
  this.plrBullets[i].update();
  if (this.plrBullets[i].alive)
  {
    nextPlrBullets.push(this.plrBullets[i]);
  }
}
this.plrBullets = nextPlrBullets;

this.x += constrain(mouseX - this.x, -10, 10);

for (let i = 0; i<eneBullets.length; i++)
{
  let c = eneBullets[i];
  if (c.x > this.x && c.x < this.x + 25 && c.y > this.y && c.y < this.y + 25) 
  {
    this.health--;
    c.alive = false;
    
    if (this.health<=0)
    {
      print("you lost")
    }
  }
}

noFill();
stroke(0,255,0);
rect(this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
}
}
class enemy{
 constructor()
{
this.x = random(15,width-15);
this.y = random(-100,0);
this.size = 25;
this.cooldown = 0;
this.alive = true;


 }
   update()
   {    
      this.y+=2.5;
     this.cooldown++;
  
  if (this.cooldown>20)
  {
  this.cooldown = 0;
  eneBullets.push(new Bullet(false,this.x,this.y));
}

let nextEneBullets = [];
for (let i = 0; i<eneBullets.length; i++)
{
  eneBullets[i].update();
  if (eneBullets[i].alive)
  {
    nextEneBullets.push(eneBullets[i]);
  }
}
eneBullets = nextEneBullets;

for (let i = 0; i<my_self.plrBullets.length; i++)
{
  let c = my_self.plrBullets[i];
  if (c.x > this.x && c.x < this.x + 25 && c.y > this.y && c.y < this.y + 25) 
  {
    this.alive = false
    c.alive = false;
  }
}

if (this.y>height+35)
{
  this.y = random(-100,0);
}

noFill();
stroke(255,0,0);
rect(this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
}
}
class Bullet{
 constructor(dir,x,y)
{
this.x = x;
this.speed = 5;
this.dir = dir;
this.alive = true;
this.y = y;
}
update()
{
if (this.dir)
{
  this.y -= this.speed;
}else{
  this.y += this.speed;
}

if (this.y<-20)
{
  this.alive = false;
}//this.y = -25;

if(this.dir)
{
  stroke(0,255,0);
}else{
  stroke(255,0,0);
}
line(this.x,this.y,this.x,this.y+25);
}
}

let my_self;
let eneBullets = [];
let enemies = [];

function setup()
{
 createCanvas(640,640);
 rectMode(CENTER);

 my_self = new myself();

 for (let i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
  enemies.push(new enemy());
}
}

function draw()
{
background(0);

if(random(1) < 0.02 && enemies.length<15){
enemies.push(new enemy());
}

my_self.update();

let newEnimies = [];
for (let i = 0; i<enemies.length; i++)
{
enemies[i].update();
if (enemies[i].alive)
{
  newEnimies.push(enemies[i]);
}
s}
enemies = newEnimies;

if (enemies.length == 0)
{
  print("you win");
}
}
```

Sorry that the collisions are a bit wacky but when converting processing to p5 here are some tips:

1: don’t use array lists use arrays with push instead of add
2: no data types only LET
3: print not println
4: class constructors are declared as “constructor” instead of class name
5: use “function” before function declaration instead of void
6: pvector is vector
7: google is your friend
8: the p5 documentation